# Ionic Datetime - use placeholder but also set the date to start

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

I need to use datetime with a placeholder that says "select your date of birth" when the datepicker is open I need the start date to be 1980, The only way I can do this currently is to set the value of the input to be 1980 but then my placeholder does not display.

Is this possible to achieve with ion-datetime ?

```
<ion-datetime 
    displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
    placeholder="select your date of birth">
</ion-datetime>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can display a label at start & then when you click on the label (on focus event or click) you set some attribute to `true` (you have to set it to false at start) & then when it's true you display the date-time picker instead using `*ngIf` (also *ngIf for the label).

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label floating color="secondary">Select Your Date of Birth</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime [(ngModel)]="dataofbirthday"  displayFormat="DD / MMMM / YYYY" pickerFormat="DD / MMMM / YYYY" monthNames='January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December' [min]="mindate" max="2019-12-31" cancelText =Cancel doneText=Select></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: But I need a placeholder not a label

Comment: <ion-datetime 
              displayFormat="DD/MM/YYYY"
              placeholder="select your date of birth" min="1980">
            </ion-datetime>